# Error in Installing Alfresco in ubuntu(Linux)

Tags: jvm, alfresco, alfresco-share

I tried installing Alfresco Document storage Server in **My Linux system**. But There is some problem which I can't fix. I Downloaded alfresco-community-3.4.a-installer-linux-x32.bin and started installing it from terminal command line code

The set up is run and at last an error pop up has come like

> **Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete
>   correctly  Error running /opt/alfresco-3.4.a/java/bin/java -jar
>   /opt/alfresco-3.4.a/bin/alfresco-mmt.jar install
>   /opt/alfresco-3.4.a/amps
>   /opt/alfresco-3.4.a/tomcat/webapps/alfresco.war -directory -nobackup :
>   Error: no `server ' JVM at`
>   /opt/alfresco-3.4.a/java/jre/lib/i386/server /libjvm.so'.**

the Installation is not yet completed ! And it says there is some error with JDK!

What is this problem and how do I rectify this?? ANy Solution??

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you running? Why are you installing such an old version of Alfresco? I have read about this problem before, try the 3.4.d edition (or 4.2.c which is the latest).

Comment: Ubuntu 12.4 Am running with. Thanks for the suggestion @ErikB

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the very old 3.4.a release was shipping with a broken installer.

Unless you have a very good reason installing that version, I would suggest to head over to http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Download_and_Install_Alfresco and get a recent 4.2.c installer.

You may even want the 64bit version if your kernel supports that architecture. Type `arch` and check whether it says "x86_64".

Comment: thanks for your suggestion ! But My system is ubuntu 12.4 ! while checking with `arch` it says **i686**. Then Shall I use 4.2.c installer??

Comment: No, the system is 32bit. The 64bit installer won't work. Go to http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-how-to-find-if-processor-is-64-bit-or-not/ and check whether your CPU is 64bit. If it is 64bit, I would reinstall the entire OS and then pick the Alfresco 64bit installer. Otherwise installation of a recent alfresco version will get a bit messy on 32bit.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to switch Ubuntu to 10.04 LTS x64 and install Alfresco 4.2d.
If you can't do that, you should download and install [Alfresco 3.4.d x86](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Community_file_list_3.4.d) version.
The file name is

> alfresco-community-3.4.d-installer-linux-x32.bin

That should work